# C# Clear Datagridview on parent form when child form closes

Tags: c#

I have an MDI application with a Datagridview control on the parent (main) form. Clicking on an item on the toolstrip menu populates the datagrid then opens the corresponding child form.

When closing the child form I want to clear the datagrid on the parent form.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When opening a new child form, hook into it's form closing or form closed event, and clear the datagridview contents at that point in the main form.

Comment: I thought it would be that simple... the Datagridview control is on the parent form. Within the form closing/closed event on the child form you cannot access the properties of the datagridview on the parent with something like "datagridview1.rows.clear" directly. Does this make sense?

Comment: True, however you're likely creating a new instance of the child form in the parent form when the DGV is clicked. There, before you call childForm.Show(); you do chilForm.FormClosing+=new EventHandler blah blah. In there, you clear your DGV.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the .Closed event on the child form. In the handler, clear the datagrid.

You might want to read up on [creating basic MDI applications in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx).